# How to calculate the proportion interest/principal of this fortnightly (bi-weekly) loan payment?

Tags: loans, interest, home-loan

> You would need to borrow $660,000 and your fortnightly payments would
>   be: Reducing loan $2,299.61 given 5.75 variable interest rate

How much of the $2300 fortnightly paid is interest, and how much is money coming off the principal?

Comment: That's all you're given?  Any other assumptions?  Are you just looking for the split of the first payment?

Comment: yeh, is it just %5.75 of the $2300 is interest, and the rest comes off the principle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you are getting the loan from a loan shark, it is the most common case that each payment is applied to the interest accrued to date and the rest is applied towards reducing the principal.  So, assuming that fortnightly means 26 equally-spaced payments during the year, the interest accrued at the end of the first fortnight is

$660,000 x (0.0575/26) = $1459.62

and so the principal is reduced by $2299.61 - $1459.62 = $839.99

For the **next** payment, the principal still owing at the beginning
of that fortnight will be $660,000-$839.99 = $659,160.01
and the interest accrued will be

$659,160.01 x (0.0575/26) = $1457.76

and so *slightly* more of the principal will be reduced than the $839.99
of the previous payment.  Lather, rinse, repeat until the loan is paid off
which should occur at the end of 17.5 years (or after 455 biweekly payments).
If the loan rate changes during this time (since you say that this is
a variable-rate loan), the numbers quoted above will change too.

And no, it is **not** the case that

> just %5.75 of the $2300 is interest, and the rest comes off the principle (sic)?

Interest is computed on the principal amount still owed ($660,000 for
starters and then decreasing fortnightly). not the loan
payment amount.

---

**Edit**  After playing around with a spreadsheet a bit, I found
that if

- payments are made every two weeks (14 days apart) rather than
  26 equally spaced payments in one year as I used above,
- interest accrues at the rate of 5.75 x (14/365)% for the 14 days
  rather than at the rate of (5.75/26)% for the time between payments
  as I used above
- each 14 days, $2299.56 is paid as the biweekly mortgage payment
  instead of the $2299.61 stated by the OP,

then 455 payments (*slightly* less than 17.5 calendar
years when leap years are taken into account) will pay
off the loan.  In fact, that 455-th payment should be reduced
by 65 cents.  In view of rounding of fractional cents and
the like, I doubt that it would be possible to have the
last equal payment reduce the balance to exactly 0.

Comment: ahok now i see, thank you Dillip for the info! Wow the banks are greedy!!!

Comment: Doesn't [fortnightly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnight) usually indicate a two week interval, i.e. 26 payments each year?

Comment: @JohnBensin You are right; I was thinking of semi-monthly, and falling into the same trap that the "we will take care of your mortgage payment" companies set when they offer to make semi-monthly payments instead of biweekly payments.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Baconbeastnz It is not the case that banks are greedy but that you are not understanding the terms of the loan agreement that you signed. If you really have borrowed $660,000 (which sounds like a jumbo mortgage loan) without understanding the terms of the loan, I strongly recommend reading a book about managing your money, such as _Consumer Reports Money Book_ to educate yourself about such interesting matters.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - Your numbers match what I calculate. Did you also calculate the full term? I get 17.5 years. You agree?

Comment: I didn't calculate the full term, but using a basic mortgage calculator (e.g the one [here](http://www.bankrate.com/partners/sem/mortgage-calculator.aspx)) gives me 455 mortgage payments of $2302.61 each instead of the $2299.61 quoted by the OP and so yes, I think the term is 17.5 years (455/26). I suspect the small difference is due to the fact that I was using a rounded-off rate instead of an exact rate; only w.xyz% can be entered.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details guys, it was a 30 year term. I know they're aren't greedy, it is quite a high rate though, such is reality! :) Thanks for the advice guys, may look at a loan around 300-400K (NZD)

Comment: @Baconbeastnz If the bank is offering a 30-year loan of $660,000 at 5.75% with a biweekly payment of about $2300 for 30 years, you _really_ are being taken to the cleaners since the loan will be paid off in about 17.5 years as first noted by JoeTaxpayer, and from then on, the bank will be laughing all the way to itself as it keeps collecting $2300 from you for the next 12.5 years. I urge you to learn more about money matters before accepting this deal.

Comment: OP has a more current question in which he linked to the bank site. As I suspected, they take a monthly payment, divide by 2, and make this the bi-weekly, dropping the amortization to 17.5 years. The process looks fine, he just needs to understand the nature of the bi-weekly loan.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I have no idea what is going on with the other question since it talks of a 30-year mortgage but the interest is calculated as if there are weekly payments due, and if the amortization schedule brings down the principal to zero in 17.5 years, then why is the property still _mortgaged_ for 12.5 years more?

Comment: It's not. The web site offers a bi-weekly. For the payment it gives the payment of 1/2 the regular payment of a 30 year amortization. Same 'trick' that any bi-weekly uses. The mortgage ends after 17.5 years.